# Switch Loop / End Line Switch - Adding a Ceiling Fan

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, receptacle, ceiling-fan

Adding a ceiling fan in a room where nothing existed before.  I have a single pole switch on the wall that controls an outlet.  When I opened the switch, it looked like it was an end-line or switch loop switch (are they the same thing?).  Only a single 14/2 wire coming in with both black and white connected to switch.

Would it be possible to tap into this as a power source for the ceiling fan addition?  I don't care if the ceiling fan is always live and controlled from the pull chains.  Or controlled from the single pole switch along with the outlet it already controls.

Comment: To boldly go where no wire has gone before, where nothing existed before , that is the mission of ... (sorry, had to). Snip me if needed!  

No, you can't tap into a switch loop for power to the fan. Can you get power from the controlled outlet to the new ceiling fan box? also, a pic of the outlet removed (WITH THE POWER TURNED OFF), and not disconnecting any wires would be helpful to better answer your question.

Comment: I take it the outlet's in the same room as the switch?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes.

Comment: Will you still want to be able to switch the outlet once the fan is installed?  If the fan has a light AND  you want the outlets unswitched going forward, than this is doable as Lucky Joestar describes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can if you’re willing to make the receptacle always hot, in which case you can repurpose the white wire to the switch box as a neutral. Basically, after turning off the power, you remove the switch first. Then, you reconnect the receptacle with your usual middle-of-the-run receptacle wiring, white to silver, black to brass, though you may have to replace the receptacle if it has the tab joining the brass terminals removed. After running new 14/3 cable to the fan from the switch box, simply join the two white wires together. If you want the fan and light controlled independently, you can put in a double switch, one switch controlling the black wire and the other controlling the red.